# What can cause bubbling mud?

Tags: trees, soil

https://vimeo.com/326120553

I have a bubbling puddle of mud near my house. It's not my water or sewage lines, I already had the water company come check it out. It doesn't smell like natural gas. What else could it be?

Note that there are two patches, both around the base of the same tree.

There was some rainy weather recently, but this is only happening around the base of one tree.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a gardening question.  Will move if we can find a home

Comment: is this a newly planted tree? And by bubbling, do you mean water bubbling to the surface or some gas/air bubbling through waterlogged soil/mud?

Comment: Windstorm? Those can move roots and leave voids. Voids fill with air, rain ensues, displaces air to surface: bubbles. Usual answer is fermentation, but there should not be anything down there to ferment that fast.

Comment: Seeing as you asked this on Home Improvement and it is a better fit there I am closing this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has already been posted on Home Improvement https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/160498/what-can-cause-bubbling-mud where it is a better fit

Comment: And they voted to close it because they think it's not home improvement.

Comment: @JK If you are really interested I suggest you go get yourself a shovel and figure out whats causing the bubbling. It could be a degrading dead animal or well.. it could be many things; hence, no one is giving you a concise answer.

Comment: it's a hydrology question